# How to UNION ALL multiple SELECT queries in VBA, without typing SQL in VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, union

I can successfully create a `UNION ALL` query using SQL to join multiple (7 total) `SELECT` queries, which were built in Design View in Access--I simply copy the SQL, create a new query, and put `UNION ALL` between them. Works just as I expect and quickly.

However, I'm often asked to modify certain aspects of the individual `SELECT` queries. Only way to recreate the query with `UNION ALL` is to copy the `SELECT` statement and paste it again.

Is there a better way to run this using `DoCmd.OpenQuery` or `RunSQL`?

I'm looking for a simple way to call a method that might look like `qry_Input_1 UNION ALL qry_Input_2` without having to retype/copy/paste the `SELECT` query every time I make a change. I'm open to either SQL or VBA approaches.

---

Here is my VBA that I started based on inputs from below (thanks @Ispep Aloc). I'm having trouble with my tempTable as suggested.

```
Sub UnionQuery()
Dim i As Integer
Dim tempTable As String
tempTable = "tbl_P54_Union"

For i = 1 To 7
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tempTable SELECT * FROM qry_P54Input_" + CStr(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the VBA code you have right now? Or are you just running the sql script? And you are using sql-server, correct?

Comment: This is MS Access. I current don't have VBA code to do anything. Although I'm open to an approach to accomplishing this in VBA. Just not sure how to "call" a query and join (i.e. UNION) them together. My SELECT queries run the calculations and pull the data.

Comment: Oops, my bad, somehow didn't see Access. Anyway, even if you create a method like you described above, you will STILL have to replace the original `SELECT` statements so it might not be worth your time.

Comment: `Run-time error '3192': Could note find output table 'tempTable'` is the error i get when i run this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still getting error... `Could not find output table 'tbl_P54_Union'.`

Comment: It would help if I used the correct names. But it works! Perfect! I need to set alerts to false... otherwise I'm prompted to OK appending rows.

Comment: Use `DB.Execute` instead of `DoCmd.RunSQL`: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-60.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a different approach to this.  Assuming your queries are named qry_Input_1, qry_Input_2, etc., I would create a for loop in VBA to populate a table with the _1, _2 be dynamic and then have a query created that simply selects from that table.  Roughly something like this

```
dim i as integer

for i = 1 to 7
    docmd.runsql "insert into temp table select * from qry_Input_" + CStr(i)
next i
```

Comment: They weren't named that way, but they are easily renamed as they are all independent queries, all with the same number of columns.